# How to access Rshiny app from machine A to machine B via lan connection?

Tags: r, server, shiny

The problem I am facing is that I am unable to run my app in machine B via lan connection. I can easily run it on machine A as I have created it there only.

`ui.R`

```
    fluidPage(
      title = 'Creating a UI from a loop',
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          # create some select inputs
          lapply(1:5, function(i) {
            selectInput(paste0('a', i), paste0('SelectA', i),
                choices = sample(LETTERS, 5))
          })
        ),

        mainPanel(
          verbatimTextOutput('a_out'),
  
          # UI output
          lapply(1:10, function(i) {
            uiOutput(paste0('b', i))
          })
        )
      )
    )
```

`server.R`

```
    function(input, output, session) {  
      output$a_out <- renderPrint({
        res <- lapply(1:5, function(i) input[[paste0('a', i)]])
        str(setNames(res, paste0('a', 1:5)))
      })

      lapply(1:10, function(i) {
        output[[paste0('b', i)]] <- renderUI({
          strong(paste0('Hi, this is output B#', i))
        })
      })
    }
```

`app.R`

```
    setwd("/home/abc/Rdeploy")
    runApp(getwd())
```

This is the web link to access the app from machine A

## 127.0.0.1:3786

So please explain me the steps to run this app in machine B also so that I can access it easily via a web link like above. Also I don't want to install shinyServer or shinyServer Pro for this simple purpose.

Answer (score 1):

This way it is available via all of your machine's IPs:

```
app <- shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
runApp(app, host = "0.0.0.0", port = 80)
```

(Port is your's to choose)

Comment: The application will have to be running on your computer for others to access, right?

Comment: Well, yes. Or any other PC/Server running R + shiny.

Comment: I have set the above code in machine A runApp(app, host = "0.0.0.0", port = 80). Now how to run it in machine B?

Comment: Open a browser on machine B and access machine A's IP/Port you specified (e.g. [http://192.168.1.2:80/](http://192.168.1.2:80/))